# Adobe Photoshop changing color of images when exporting? Why? Making them more yellow

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors, export

I'm working with Lightroom and photoshop, getting photos ready then exporting them to Photoshop, finishing up and then exporting.. Problem is, when final images are exported, they suddenly change colour hue/ saturation etc. Seem to get a lot yellower..

Can anyone help please!? This is killing me, I just can't work it out..

Thanks.

Comment: The question better suits at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need to get to grips with color profiles and color management. *Until you fully understand I recommend that you edit / save / load with no other setting than sRGB*.

Comment: The most common problem here is the color management. Try to [fix it by setting `sRGB IEC61966-2.1` as default](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-fix-windows-photo-viewer-displaying-yellow-or-orange-tint-for-white-and-transparent-images)

Comment: Color management basics: http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/color-management-printing.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s because of 3 reasons.

1. In windows 8 version picture viewer, some of the photoshped images are seems to be very yellowish, in this case nothing to worry. It’s just a picture viewer software error. You will get the perfect image while printing. Install new image viewer software like Picasa and check.
2. Check whether you have calibrated your monitor properly using the CD available along the product or download the proper software and update.
3. Profile issue with Photoshop. Just check the raw/image and the Photoshop have same profile.
   Just go to the image property, detail tab and check the color representation and go to Photoshop assign profile option available in edit menu to check the profile is matching with original photo. If not, assign the same profile in which the image has been taken.

Basically original photo and the working profile should be same.